# more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `$geoNear` and `near` inside the aggregate in MongoDB. I have **hosted my MongoDB database into mlabs**. And **everything working fine on my local**, But don't know why when I deploy my app to live and I am getting the below error:

> > "geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear on

Below is the code which I have used:

```
Shops.aggregate([
  {
     $geoNear: {
         near: { 
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: coordinates
         },
         distanceField: "dist.calculated",
         maxDistance: 80467,
         spherical: true
     }
  }
])
.then((products)=>{
      res.json(products);
})
```

Can anyone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 9):

As the error message indicated, this is because you have more than one `2dsphere` indexes, so `$geoNear` doesn't know which one to use.

In this situation, you can either:

- drop the second geo index, or
- use the `key` parameter as mentioned in the [$geoNear documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/):

> If your collection has multiple 2d and/or multiple 2dsphere indexes, you must use the key option to specify the indexed field path to use. Specify Which Geospatial Index to Use provides a full example.

The error is mentioned in the docs as well:

> If there is more than one 2d index or more than one 2dsphere index and you do not specify a key, MongoDB will return an error.

You can use [db.collection.getIndexes()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) to list all indexes defined on the collection.

Here's an example of using the `key` parameter:

```
> db.test.insert([
  {_id:0, loc1:{type:'Point',coordinates:[1,1]}, loc2:{type:'Point',coordinates:[2,2]}},
  {_id:1, loc1:{type:'Point',coordinates:[2,2]}, loc2:{type:'Point',coordinates:[1,1]}}
])
```

Then I create two `2dsphere` indexes:

```
> db.test.createIndex({loc1:'2dsphere'})
> db.test.createIndex({loc2:'2dsphere'})
```

Running `$geoNear` without specifying `key` will output the error:

```
> db.test.aggregate({$geoNear:{near:{type:'Point',coordinates:[0,0]},distanceField:'d'}})
...
  "errmsg": "more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear on",
...
```

Using `key: loc1` will sort the result according to the `loc1` index (`_id: 0` comes before `_id: 1`):

```
> db.test.aggregate(
    {$geoNear: {
        near: {type: 'Point',coordinates: [0,0]},
        distanceField: 'd',
        key: 'loc1'}})
{ "_id": 0, "loc1": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] }, "loc2": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] }, "d": 157424.6238723255 }
{ "_id": 1, "loc1": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] }, "loc2": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] }, "d": 314825.2636028646 }
```

And, using `key: loc2` will sort the result according to the `loc2` index (`_id: 1` comes before `_id: 0`):

```
> db.test.aggregate(
    {$geoNear: {
        near: {type: 'Point',coordinates: [0,0]},
        distanceField: 'd',
        key: 'loc2'}})
{ "_id": 1, "loc1": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] }, "loc2": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] }, "d": 157424.6238723255 }
{ "_id": 0, "loc1": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] }, "loc2": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] }, "d": 314825.2636028646 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I already mentioned in my question that I am using mlabs. So how can I run any MongoDB command there?

Comment: You should be able to access mlab deployments using the command line. Otherwise, add the `key` parameter like I mentioned in the answer in your code.