# more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear on

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting an error of "more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear on", I used the key notation to specify which field but I am still getting the error , I am stuck !

this is the structure of my doc in my mongodb

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ".."
    },
    "name": "Donna",
        .
        .
        .

    "cor": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -79.3935716,
            43.6872606
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
pipeline=[
                   {
                     $geoNear: {
                        near: { type: "Point", 
                                                 coordinates: [43.653225 ,-79.383186] },
                        key: "cor",
                        distanceField: "distance",
                        query: filter
                     }
                   },
                   { $sort: { "distance": 1} },
                   { $limit: 10}
                ]

db.collection(THERAPISTS_COLLECTION).createIndex({cor: "2dsphere"});
db.collection(THERAPISTS_COLLECTION).aggregate(pipeline).toArray(function (err, therapists) {

)};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [more than one 2dsphere index, not sure which to run geoNear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562394/more-than-one-2dsphere-index-not-sure-which-to-run-geonear)

Comment: In that thread he did not use the "key" notation when Using geonear but I am and I am still getting that error !!

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Could you clarify what other geospatial indexes are defined on the collection? Also, which version of MongoDB is being used? You should be able to see this by running `db.version()`